# Why am I unable to consolidate the score?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity. I need to consolidate the score for a game. I am unable to keep the score and post it to another scene in unity.

How can this be done?

```
    #pragma strict
    private var playerAnswer = "";
    var score : int = 0; 
    var number : int;
    var number2: int;
    var answer : int;



    function Start() 
    {
      number = Random.Range(2,12);
      number2= Random.Range(2,12);

      answer = number*number2;
    }

    function OnGUI() 
    {
      var guiStyleA =GUI.skin.GetStyle("Button");
      guiStyleA.fontSize = 20;
      guiStyleA.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;

      var guiStyleB = GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label");
      guiStyleB.fontSize = 25;
      guiStyleB.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;


      GUI.skin.textField.fontSize =20;
      GUI.Box(Rect (150,10,50,30),score.ToString());
      GUI.Label(Rect(0,10,200,150), number + " X "+ number2 + " = ");   
      playerAnswer = GUI.TextField ( Rect (150, 70, 30, 30), playerAnswer);

      if ( GUI.Button ( Rect (70, 115, 70, 40) , "Submit" ) )
      { //just a button
        CheckAnswer();
      }
    }

    function CheckAnswer()
    {
      if ( playerAnswer == answer)
      {
        score += 1;
         print("Correct");
      } 
      else 
      {
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store variables between scene, you can use Unity [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)
Here is an example:

```
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", 10);
```

The first parameter is the key that we'll be used to get the stored variable in the futur and the second parameter is the value.

Then in another scene, if you want to get the player score, all you need to do is a `GetInt` :

```
print (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score"))
```

You can also store string or float with `PlayerPrefs.SetString` and `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

@Gary Olsson solution is okay, but not only one and in my opinion not the best aproach (access to device storage).

Apart from using `PlayerPrefs` you have options like:

1. Make one gameObject not be destoryed between loading scenes and keep the values in it. To do so, assign to that gameObject component and on `Awake` call `DontDestroyOnLoad`
2. Use static variables or properties. They live as long as the application.